# Complex editing of names by staff type

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I want to add a prefix to a specific staff type and not to another, within a column of my report; by saying

```
If {staff type} = {doctor} then add 'dr' to the name, 
If {staff type} = {nurse} then don't add dr
```

but I've had trouble finding a way to do it as the only other ways I've seen if, then formula is that they usually don't involve two tables and I don't know how to join them. They usually say; `if {target} >500 then exceeded, if {target} <500 then below.`

Grateful to suggestions.

Not familiar with CR syntax so please be clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
If {staff type} = {doctor}

 then "dr " + <<Database field.name>> 

else If {staff type} = {nurse} 

then <<Database field.name>>
```